# Modifying a Depth First Search Algorithm using an Adjacency Matrix to search for specific end-node

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode, adjacency-matrix

So I have an adjacency matrix of size `N x N` for a graph with `N` nodes. I would like to conduct a [Depth First Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) through this matrix in order to find if a path does or does not exist from a `Source` node to a `Destination` node. If it exists I would like to print the path.

In the psuedocode below, it uses a matrix/graph `G` to find all vertices that can be accessed with a starting node of `v`. How would I modify this algorithm so I can have something similar to this: `procedure DFS(G,v,d)` where `d` is the target node I am searching for?

```
procedure DFS(G,v):
    label v as discovered
    for all edges from v to w in G.adjacentEdges(v) do
        if vertex w is not labeled as discovered then
            recursively call DFS(G,w)
```

Also as a sidenote, how would I add the ability to return the total weight of all the edges for the path that it discovered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm needs to be modified in two ways

1. it needs to stop when it finds the destination
2. it needs to produce a path to the destination

In the pseudocode below, the path variable `P` starts as an empty list. When the destination is found, the destination node is placed in `P`. Then as each level of recursion returns, the current node `w` is appended to the path. When the top-level call returns, `P` contains the full path. There's only one problem, the path is in reverse: destination to source. So you'll have to turn it around.

```
procedure DFS(G,v,d,P=empty):
    if v equals d
        initialize P with d
        return P
    label v as discovered
    for all edges from v to w in G.adjacentEdges(v) do
        if vertex w is not labeled as discovered then
            recursively call DFS(G,w,d,P)
            if P is not empty
                append v to P
                return P
    return empty
```

Comment: I will try implementing this, could you also see if you can add in my sidenote?

Comment: @Annabelle Once you have the final path, you can find the weight of each edge from the adjacency matrix. So follow the path from start to destination while adding up the weights.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work exactly as intended. For example: Path from node 3 to 6 returns: 6 6 5 1 2. When it should be returning 6 5 1 2 3?

Comment: @Annabelle Yes, quite right. I've updated the answer.